# Memoir not Obeying Lower Margins

Tags: margins, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class to typeset my thesis, with the following commands to specify the margins

```
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1in}{*}  %% 1.5in upper margin, 1in lower margin
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1in}{*}
\setheaderspaces{1in}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

and I declare the document class using

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper,12pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

When I run Latex, I get the following output

```
******************************************************
Stock height and width: 794.96999pt by 614.295pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 794.96999pt by 614.295pt
Text height and width: 621pt by 433pt
Spine and edge margins: 108.405pt and 72.26999pt
Upper and lower margins: 108.405pt and 65.56499pt
Headheight and headsep: 14.5pt and 21.63501pt
...
```

The lower margin, 65.56499pt, converts to 0.91in, and the resulting pdf shows the margin to be a little less than 1in. I don't understand why the margin isn't being set at exactly 1in. The other margins appear to be fine. Even if I directly specify the lower margin to be 72pt, it still ends up as 65.5pt.

Comment: Please read the manual for an explanation on what `\checkandfixthelayout` does. It will adjust the text height and thus the bottom margin such the text height match an integral number of lines. The algorithm can be changed with an option as explained in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `\checkandfixthelayout` algorithm, as daleif suggested, took care of the problem. In ended up using `\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]`, which is described in the "Laying out the page" section in the manual.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this may lead to extra stretching on pages. I usually use `\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]`

Comment: I also tried `nearest`, and it still bled over. I have strict requirements on the margins, and they must be 1in or greater, and `fixed` seems to be the only way to ensure this.

Comment: Strange requirement. But using no option should give you at least 1in at the bottom. It gets as close to but not exceeding what you are asking for